# My imageview is not getting fill-parent

Tags: java, android, xml

My image view doesn't set `fill-parent` in my layout. I have some images with a size of `500*375` and `300*215`. I set my image view to `fill-parent` completely, but it appears in the center of the page without a complete fill..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/main_matn_layout"
            android:background="@drawable/backmainmatn"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ir.adad.AdView
        android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/star"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/main_matn_i_next"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/main_matn_i_pre"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imgb"
        />


<ImageButton   android:id="@+id/imgb"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
               android:layout_gravity="center"
               android:background="@drawable/star"
               android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/main_matn_i_next"
               android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/main_matn_i_pre"
        />


<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/main_matn_titr"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="30sp"/>

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/main_matn_share"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/share"/>
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/main_matn_img"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/main_matn_matn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="TextView"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/main_matn_i_next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/back"/>

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/main_matn_i_pre"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/next"/>
```

I want to make my `imageview` `fill-parent`.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/main_matn_img"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
```

In the emulator it appears correctly, but when I run my project it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, `fill_parent` is deprecated, you should use `match_parent` instead.

That said, I'm guessing this could be a `scaleType` issue. To check that your `ImageView` is actually filling its parent, I suggest setting a background color:

```
android:background="#FF0000"
```

To make sure the bitmap actually fills its `ImageView` container, try the `scaleType` which better fits your needs:

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```